# Fail to checkout files from another local branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

```
$ pwd
/sandbox/views/projectOne/Messages/src

$ git branch
  bugfix/F1
  feature/F2
* feature/F3
  master

$ git checkout feature/F2 -- Messages/src/*.cpp
error: pathspec 'Messages/src/*.cpp' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout feature/F2 -- Messages/src/Hello.h
error: pathspec 'Messages/src/Hello.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout feature/F2 -- /Messages/src/Hello.h
fatal: Could not switch to '/Messages/': No such file or directory    

$ git checkout feature/F2  /Messages/src/Hello.h
fatal: Could not switch to '/Messages/': No such file or directory

$ git checkout feature/F2  Messages/src/Hello.h
error: pathspec 'Messages/src/Hello.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Early, I am able to use the following command without issues:

```
$ git checkout master -- Messages/src/Hello.h
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by this:

> pwd /sandbox/views/projectOne/Messages/src

I'm guessing that you are not in the project root but inside `src/Messages`.

Try this way:

```
git checkout feature/F2 -- Hello.h
```

Comment: it works now! so the checkout directory is related to my current git directory.